# Prevent user access to particular URL

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

I am using JSF2 and Spring Security. I know that if we want to hide some fields on the view we just use the render attribute. But if I want to prevent a logged user access to a view (by URL), how can I do that? 
Does the SpringSecurity support any filters for this?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) for this.

[Restriction on Restricted pages when logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274696/jsf-servletfilter-restriction-on-restricted-pages-when-logged-in) answer should give you more details.

Comment: Thank Vikas V, I have a more question that if the SpringSecurity supported any filter for this or not?

Comment: @LatentBoy This should help  [Spring security filter chain](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html)

Comment: This answer is so unhelpful. OP is using Spring Security and this answer doesn't seem to explain in any way how to configure Spring Security accordingly, but instead recommends to homegrow security using a custom filter, completely working around Spring Security. This makes no sense.